# How to customize a jquery slider in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm currently working on a WordPress website for which I had to create a custom jQuery slider form. I set up everything locally first and then moved the slider to my WordPress page. I managed to apply my custom CSS and jQuery but my mobile form slider looks like this

**Current**

[image]

While it should look like this (and it does locally):

**Desired**

[image]

Comment: Can you post what css files you are linking to your page? Do you have the jquery mobile css file linked? See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider

Comment: Yes, mobile css file is visible in head of the page when I inspect it. [link](http://imgur.com/pGkiZxe)

Comment: Could be that some css rules are missing or being overwritten by other css files. I would suggest inspecting the slider element on both local and live and see what the difference is for css. Also making sure to clear the cache and refresh page to have the latest files included.

Comment: If you ask a question, it should be a question, and not a *** tag cloud.